# Added an external folder to a project in PHPStorm on MacOS Mojave

Tags: linux, macos, bash, git, phpstorm

I'm working in PHP Storm, on a project that's using a package I'm developing in tandem. I've had a couple of workflows for this, but I'd really like to add an external directory (the package source) to my project without impacting the local git or editing in the vendor directory.

Some preamble workflows that I've tried from slowest to fastest, any advice on a better way would be appreciated.

**Attempt 1 Slowest**
I kept 2 projects open in phpstorm. I'd have to:

1. Work on the active project.
2. Make the change I needed in the `vendor directory` (yikes!)
3. Copy the change into the `package project`
4. Commit the changes in the `package project`
5. Wait for packagist to get the updated repo
6. Do a composer update

**Attempt 2 Pretty Fast but with pain points**
I keep 1 active project open in phpstorm. And use simlinks to override the project in the vendor directory to always be the direct code.

The repositories key in `composer.json` needs to have the path to your code.

1. Work on the active project.
2. Make the change I needed in the `vendor directory` (now the actual repo)
3. Commit the changes in the `package project` without pushing
4. Remove the repositories key in your `composer.json`temporarily
5. commit the update to the main project
6. Put the repositories key back in composer.json

This is fast but if you forget the composer.json repositories key you are going to blow up your project and it's less trivial to update composer.json and composer lock in production

**Attempt 3 Also Fast but with other pain points**
I keep 2 active projects open in phpstorm.

https://github.com/franzliedke/studio

It short circuits everything for you, and is basically the best of both worlds, but you still need two different projects open and have to wait for a composer update to refresh the project in your vendor directory. Plus there is a fair amount of screen switching which can be a bit of a pain when you are going back and forth with web results terminal, git and now another code editing screen.

1. Work on the active project.
2. Make the change I needed in the the actual repo (another screen)
3. Commit the changes in the `package project` without pushing
4. Run a composer update

This is fast but not as fast as working in the vendor directory, yet safer. The problem is always in the main project and then requiring a composer update to reflect the changes.

**Wishful Solution**
1. Have an external link in phpstorm where you can pull in the project src directory. Basically the IDE letting me edit the other package files much like when I was working in the linked vendor.
2. Sim linking the project repo into the vendor so it's always up to date as I edit in the IDE folder.
3. Then the only thing needed is an app or terminal to commit the `package project` incrementally as needed.

Any advice would be appreciated
Sorry this was super long... 3 cheers for you for making it to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workflow that works for me. This isn't neccessarily the best for everyone, but it accomplishes letting me import a package into the project while the package is in active development without a phpstorm utility to let you include that directory.

Basically I use Approach 3, which uses studio to make soft links from your vendor directory package to the code of the package. However instead of editing it in another editor window or in the vendor directory I make a `vendor-dev` directory and simply add /vendor-dev to my `.gitignore'. This essetially lets me bring in any outside code into the project and work on them simultaneously while not touching the vendor directory and further version control will never trigger.

The last benefit of this is another suprising speed boost where I don't have to search out all the vendor directory for my package and/or the specific files I'm working on. I could just link to the package which is nice, but I can also just link to the specific files I'm working on like a class, service provider or console command.

I hope this helps your productivity.
Find something better feel free to leave a comment.